# How to retrieve product/order return information via PrestaShop 8 API?

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce

I'm working with the PrestaShop 8 API and struggling to find the API endpoint for fetching product return details.

Does anyone know which API endpoint in PrestaShop 8 can be used for retrieving this information? I've checked the general order-related endpoints without luck. Any examples or pointers to the documentation would be really helpful.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a missing resource - A PR on this matter had been recently merged to be included in Prestashop 9, in the meantime you can patch your website by adding

```
 'order_returns' => ['description' => 'The Customers orders returns', 'class' => 'OrderReturn'],
```

in getResources() method of **classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php**